# How do I get the current TTY device in Node?

Tags: node.js, bash, tty, pty

I'm trying to get the path of the device of my current TTY/PTY.

If I run `tty` in a shell, it tells me the device of the current TTY, but if I use `child_process` to run `tty` I get an error. I've also tried `fs.readlinkSync('/proc/self/fd/0')` but it also doesn't work.

What I've tried:

```
luis@Iphone-47 ~ % tty
/dev/ttys003
luis@Iphone-47 ~ % node
Welcome to Node.js v19.7.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const cp = require('child_process')
undefined
> try { cp.execSync('tty') } catch (err) { console.log(err.stdout.toString()) }
not a tty

undefined
>
```

Is there a cross-platform way to do this?

**Edit:** this works in Python, so why not in Node?

```py
luis@Iphone-47 ~ % python3
Python 3.9.1 (v3.9.1:1e5d33e9b9, Dec  7 2020, 12:10:52) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.system('tty')
/dev/ttys001
0
>>>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error you get, and maybe also explain why you want to know the path to the TTY device

Comment: @M.Becerra the error I get is in the screenshot. It just says `not a tty`

Comment: Please [do not upload images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Paste the relevant text into the question and format for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out after reading [a very long issue on GitHub](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/367).

The trick is to set `stdio` to inherit `stdin`, and pipe `stdout` and `stderr`:

```js
const cp = require('child_process');

const ttyPath = cp.execSync('tty', {
  stdio: [
    'inherit',
    'pipe',
    'pipe'
  ]
}).toString().trim();
```

Comment: Note that for some reason, this only works with `execSync` and not `exec` (unless I did something wrong)